# Why am I getting this error?

Tags: infectonator-3

On a save I've had about a week or two, every time I try to open the game, I get this screen, which is very weird! Clicking anything like countries or the leave button does nothing, and the pause button is in the wrong language. I apparently have a lot of money - too much, and this is crazy. What happened?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [this website](https://steamcommunity.com/app/666570/discussions/1/1727575977595861790/), it highlights some bugs people have found. One of them is:

> Game freezes in World Map and DNA/Days counter become "123"

and the developer said:

> *kerissakti  [Developer] Jul 11, 2018 @ 5:14am*
>
> Hi everyone,
> We've uploaded a new patch ver 1.3.2.2 to fix these issues. ......
> Please let me know if the problem still persists, we'll do our best to resolve it as soon as possible

So I think that it should resolve, and if it does not, try asking for bugfixes on Steam Support.
And yes, your pause button is in Indonesian, but I don't know why.